# Finding the mean and median using a cumulative distribution function

Tags: calculus

Here is the question:

> A quantity $x$ has cumulative distribution function
>
> $$P(x) = \begin{cases}x − \frac{x^2}4&\text{for }0\le x\le2\\0&\text{for }x < 0\\1&\text{for }x > 2\end{cases}$$
>
> Find the mean and median of $x$.

I know the limits of integration are from $0$ to $2$. Can someone help me get started finding the mean and median in this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The median is the $x$ where $P(x)=\frac 12$.  Read the definition for a continuous distribution.  For the mean, compute the probability mass distribution as $p(x)=\frac d{dx}P(x)$.  Then the mean is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xp(x)dx$  Integration by parts might make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Mean:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xP'(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^2x\left(1-\frac x2\right)\,\mathrm dx=\frac23$$

Median (denoted $m$ below):

$$\int_{-\infty}^m P'(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^m\left(1-\frac x2\right)\,\mathrm dx=m-\frac{m^2}4=\frac12\implies m=2\pm\sqrt2$$

but only one of these lies in the support of $x$, so $m=2-\sqrt2\approx0.586$.